# Would time continue to flow forever in a curved spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity

Based on geometry,the surface of a sphere or any curved surface would not going to be infinite on the line.
as we continue moving on ,we'll finally meet up the old position again.
In this case,a sphere is a curved surface.
in spacetime we're also constantly moving through,so if this consequense is true,then would it be a loop in the flow of time?

Comment: Although the description of time as flowing may date from the medieval use of water clocks and from observation of tides, it's usually considered to be a dimension analogous to the spatial ones, as a result of that "spatialization of time" which is often felt to describe an aspect of General Relativity, whose material objects move with a rapidity that's a combination of motion through space and through time:  However, the water analogy's also used in modern descriptions of space, as in the "river model" of black holes, described at https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0411060.pdf .

Answer (score 3):

No.  Note that *curved* is not the same as *[closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Closed_surfaces)*.  For instance, an infinite plane which is distorted so it has small hills and valleys would have curvature, but would not be closed like a sphere is.